# ExtJs Load Data From YQL: Error Parsing When results is null

Tags: extjs, extjs4, jsonp, yql

I have a `store` that is loaded from [yql request](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20local.search%20where%20zip=%2768007%27%20and%20query=%27pizza%27;&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=hello).  My query works correctly when data is returned however it **throws an exception** when results is `null`.

The issue is that the root where the data is derived is nested twice in the response. ie. `results.Result`

The exception i receive is: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Result' of null`

My current model with proxy info:

```
Ext.define('ExtYqlApp.model.results.resultsGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'Title', type: 'auto' },
        { name: 'Address', type: 'auto' },
        { name: 'City', type: 'auto' },
        { name: 'State', type: 'auto' },
        { name: 'Phone', type: 'auto' },
        { name: 'Latitude', type: 'auto' },
        { name: 'Longitude', type: 'auto' },
        { name: 'Rating.AverageRating', type: 'auto' },
        { name: 'BusinessUrl', type: 'auto' }
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',
        extraParams: {
            'q': "select * from local.search where zip='68007' and query='pizza'",
            'format': 'json',
            'diagnostics': false
        },
        headers: { 'Content-type': 'text/json;  charset=utf-8', 'Accepts': 'text/json' },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'query.results.Result',
            successProperty: ''
        }
    }
});
```

I have tried setting root instead to 'query.results' and implementing `mappings` on the fields ie. `Result.Title`, however this didn't work either.

Is there an `event` i could listen to that would allow me to check the raw data prior to the store `load`?